# How to split a string from the first space occurrence only Java

Tags: java, string

I tried to split a string using string.Index and string.length but I get an error that string is out of range. How can I fix that?

```
while (in.hasNextLine())  {

    String temp = in.nextLine().replaceAll("[<>]", "");
    temp.trim();

    String nickname = temp.substring(temp.indexOf(' '));
    String content = temp.substring(' ' + temp.length()-1);

    System.out.println(content);
```

Comment: Consider what happens if there is no `' '` in `temp`, then handle that case.

Comment: `' '` has an ASCII value of 32, so `' ' + temp.length()-1` is going to be larger than 32, and I doubt `temp.length()` is larger than 32. You need to use `temp.indexOf(' ')` instead of just `' '` and don't add `temp.length()-1`.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Must be some around this:

```
String nickname = temp.substring(0, temp.indexOf(' '));
String content = temp.substring(temp.indexOf(' ') + 1);
```

Answer (score 69):

Use the java.lang.String split function with a limit.

```
String foo = "some string with spaces";
String parts[] = foo.split(" ", 2);
System.out.println(String.format("cr: %s, cdr: %s", parts[0], parts[1]));
```

You will get:

```
cr: some, cdr: string with spaces
```

Answer (score 7):

```
string.split(" ",2)
```

split takes a limit input restricting the number of times the pattern is applied.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String,%20int)

Answer (score 0):

```
String string = "This is test string on web";
String splitData[] = string.split("\\s", 2);

Result ::
splitData[0] =>  This
splitData[1] =>  is test string  


String string = "This is test string on web";
String splitData[] = string.split("\\s", 3);

Result ::
splitData[0] =>  This
splitData[1] =>  is
splitData[1] =>  test string on web
```

By default split method create n number's of arrays on the basis of given regex.
But if you want to restrict number of arrays to create after a split than pass second argument as an integer argument.